# Asana API (Java) - Fetching the tasks's due date

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am using the API code developed in Java and I am trying to obtain the due date for a task. When I use the following lines of code, I get "null":

```
List<Task> tasks = client.tasks.findByProject(demoProject.id).execute();

for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++)
    {
        if(tasks.get(i).id.equals("............"))
        {
            System.out.println(tasks.get(i).name +", "+ tasks.get(i).dueOn);
        }
    }
```

Could somebody get back to me on this please? I have posted ".........." for the task ID, but it is a valid ID.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `null`? Does it enter in `for`, in `if`? It's better to change `tasks.get(i).id.equals("............")` to `tasks != null && tasks.get(i) != null && "............".equals(tasks.get(i).id)` ...

Comment: My "Task" list isn't empty. However, I tried adding the conditions into the "and" statement, and it still doesn't work. "Null" is the value that gets printed when I try to retrieve the due date for the specified task ID. There is a valid due date set for that task. It is not just that task, when I loop through all the tasks in the project, all the due dates have null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at Asana.
It looks like the endpoint you are using returns a compact representation (name and id only).

You'll need to specify the fields you want to include in options like so:
List tasks = client.tasks.findByProject(<"....">)**.option("fields", "name,due_on")**.execute();

Hope this helps!

For reference:

https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query
https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options